# calling constructor through array of objects

Tags: java, constructor, calling-convention

```
class A
{
  static int i;
  A()
  {
    System.out.println(++i);
  }
  public static void main(String h[])
  {
    A obj[] = new A[30]; 
  }
}
```

> A obj[30] = new A[30]; :- this line should invoke the default
>   constructor 30 times ?

Comment: if I take an ineteger(not static) lets say int b; then obj[0].b=1; says null pointer exception, fine i understand. But howcome obj[0].i=3; works ?

Comment: It works because `i` is static and does not need any instance of `A` to hold a value.

Answer (score 13):

The line

```
A obj[30] = new A[30];
```

does not call the constructor for `A`. It creates 30 uninstantiated references to `A`;

To instantiate the 30 object references, you can use:

```
A obj[] = { new A(), new A(), ..28 more ->
};
```

or better in this case given the number of elements:

```
for (int i=0; i < obj.length; i++) {
   obj[i] = new A();
}
```

Note, the first use of `30` in the array size declaration is illegal.

```
A obj[30] = new A[30];
      ^
```

Comment: It has been a while since I used c++, but I don't believe it would have constructed 30 instances of `A`...?

Comment: A obj[30] = new A[30];... sorry for the typo. and I wanted an implementation w/o loops or recursion so thanks for the first method

Comment: Hello, I was wondering if it would be possible to use the "enhanced" for loop to do this: `for (A a : obj) { a = new A(); }`

Comment: @Gruvw no because enhanced loops dont have a reference to the index needed to assign the new instance

Answer (score 2):

No, this line does not invoke constructor at all. It just creates 30 elements long array of type `A`. Each element of array is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do exactly what you want to do, but here are two things that come very close, both calling the default constructor 30 times:

```
A *obj = new A[30];
```

or

```
A obj[30];
```

The first answer will create an array of 30 A objects on the heap, calling the default constructor for each one of them. obj can be passed back to callers of this function since it is not on the stack. The problem is, obj no longer has a type of A[30], so sizeof(obj) will be different from the code in the original question. (Note that "delete []" must be used for obj, not just "delete".)

The second answer will create an array of 30 A objects on the stack. Now the compiler will understand the obj has 30 elements, and sizeof(obj) will be the same as in your question. However, obj can only be used within this function (or functions that it calls) because once the function returns, it will be eliminated from the stack, calling 30 destructors in the process. (It is a local variable only.)

With C++ (or any good object oriented language), creating an object always means both allocating the space and calling the constructor. Otherwise, you really don't have a useful object. So, when an object is created in any supported way (local variable or "new" for C++), it always calls the default constructor for every object you created and now have access to. (Note that if there were no default constructor, then neither answers would even compile!)